# Mysql populate serial number column based on pattern

Tags: mysql

I need to populate a table with x number of serial numbers.  Each serial number should follow the pattern A000001, A000002, A000003, etc.

I have the following I wrote from SQL Server but having issues converting it to mysql.

```
SELECT CHAR(ASCII('A') + @var / 1000000) + RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6),(@var % 1000000)),6)
```

Basically, I can just stick this into a WHILE loop and replace @var with the next number.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you selecting it from exiting table rows ?, if yes provide table structure

Comment: No, I'm not.  I'm pre-loading a table with these generated numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`LPAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function to add the prefix before the number:

```
SELECT LPAD(@var, 7, 'A000000')
```